# Mysterious .zip File

Tags: linux, download

I've booted into Linux (KNOPPIX 7.2(?) on a flash drive) on my father's old laptop and have been looking around the hard drive a bit. In his Downloads folder, I have found a zipped folder called "fkeylogger.zip". Inside is a single setup.exe file. Can anyone tell me what this folder and file is and where it may have originated from?

Comment: It could be anything.

Comment: It could possibly be [Free KeyLogger](http://hackingengineering.blogspot.co.nz/2011/10/download-free-keylogger-32.html), but any further investigation is at your own risk.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, Mike. I might as well just leave it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way which might help to determine what the file is would be to product the md5sum for the zip file, then paste the md5sum into Google.  (You can probably do something similar with sha1sum to generate an equivalent sha1 sum)

To do this under most versions of linux just type "md5sum fkeylogger.zip"

This is quite safe to do as it simply calculates a hash of the file.   Chances are pretty good - as others have mentioned - that this is "Free Keylogger".  You should be able to verify this based on the MD5sum - particularly if its a common file or a common virus/trojan payload.

Comment: Confirmed, it is a "Free Keylogger". Thanks for the help!